# How center the title of AlertDialog in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I need center the title of AlertDialog in Android Studio, I have tried several forms but without success, someone can tell me if this is possible and how to do it?

Here is my code

```
public class ExampleDialog extends AppCompatDialogFragment {
private EditText myIpAddress;
private EditText myIpPort;
private ExampleDialogListener listener;
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_dialog, null);

    builder.setView(view)
            .setTitle("Configuracion WIFI")
            .setMessage("Ingrese la IP y el Puerto del Relay Remoto ")
            .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                }
            })
            .setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    String username = myIpAddress.getText().toString();
                    String password = myIpPort.getText().toString();
                    listener.applyTexts(username, password);
                }
            });
    myIpAddress = view.findViewById(R.id.etx_ipAddress);
    myIpPort = view.findViewById(R.id.etx_ipPort);
    return builder.create();
}
```

Comment: create your own xml file and center the text through the xml.

Comment: This is a good tutorial: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-implement-a-custom-alertdialog-view-in-android

Comment: use DialogFragment instead of AlertDialog

Answer (score 0):

in layout_dialog.xml

```
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/title"
  layout_width="match_parent"
  layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:gravity="center"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a custom style:

```
new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context,
        R.style.MaterialAlertDialog_Title_Center)
        .setTitle("Title")
        ...
        .show();
```

with:

```
  <style name="MaterialAlertDialog_Title_Center" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">
    <item name="materialAlertDialogTitlePanelStyle">@style/Title.Panel.Center</item>
  </style>

  <style name="Title.Panel.Center" parent="MaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents.Title.Panel">
    <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
  </style>
```

[image]